# Why will MKCoordinateRegion not show a small region?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkcoordinateregion

I have the following code to set an MKCoordinateRegion to an MKMapView:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    mapView.setUserTrackingMode(.followWithHeading, animated: true)

    currentLocationCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: mapView.userLocation.coordinate, latitudinalMeters: 25, longitudinalMeters: 25)
    mapView.setRegion(currentLocationCoordinateRegion, animated: true)

    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone

    let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()

    if status == .authorizedAlways || status == .authorizedWhenInUse, status == .restricted {

    } else {

        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    }

}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation) {

    if currentLocationCoordinateRegion == nil {

        currentLocationCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: mapView.userLocation.coordinate, latitudinalMeters: 25, longitudinalMeters: 25)

        mapView.setRegion(currentLocationCoordinateRegion, animated: true)

    }

}
```

However, the map view shows a region that is much larger than 20 meters by 20 meters.

What is the problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: There is no problem and there is nothing to fix.

Comment: @matt Does the map view have a limit on how small a region it could show? When I use gestures on the map view I am able to zoom in further.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running that code after the first time it is run, and the second time it works. It just doesn't zoom completely the first time.

Comment: When exactly did you run it the first time? In what method?

Comment: In the mapView(_:didUpdate:) callback method of the MKMapViewDelegate protocol. I think it fires the first time when the view controller shows.

Comment: That sounds circular/ineffective. Is your map view actively tracking the user's location? You cannot set the region while it is doing that. Please revise your question to show _real code in its actual context_. Show enough code to describe a reproducible issue.

Comment: @matt My map view starts tracking the user's location when I set the showUserLocation property to true in viewDidLoad().

Comment: @matt I updated the post with more complete code. I added code to set the coordinate region in viewDidLoad().

Comment: @matt Running that code to set the region in viewDidLoad() does not fix the problem. MKMapView still won't show a small region until the second time the code to set the region is run.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably here:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation) {
    if currentLocationCoordinateRegion == nil { // <--
        currentLocationCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: mapView.userLocation.coordinate, latitudinalMeters: 25, longitudinalMeters: 25)
        mapView.setRegion(currentLocationCoordinateRegion, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Here's my theory. As we get started, Core Location tries to get a fix on the user's location. At first it has only a vague idea where the user is, and you get `didUpdate`. But then (with luck) it gets better and better ideas where the user, and you get `didUpdate` *again*. And again. And again, until we have a good fix. But you are throwing away the second, third, fourth updates — you stop as soon as you get the *first* update. That, I'm suggesting, would be why it works better the second time; Core Location has had time to get a better fix.